# Не получается закрыть доступ по IP

Tags: .htaccess, сервер, ip

В htaccess
прописал директиву

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 104.254.244.128
Deny from 173.245.58.177
Deny from 78.110.60.230
Deny from 173.245.58.110
Deny from 64.13.232.232
Deny from 213.133.100.100
Deny from 104.254.244.128
Deny from 78.110.60.230
```

Но как заходили, так и заходят, прописал свой ip, заходит. Сервер Apache+Nginx
Как блокировать по ip правильно? Спасибо

Comment: Вроде всё правильно. Файл .htaccess точно назвали без ошибок?

Comment: @Viktor Tomilov Да, так и есть

Comment: А лог какого из серверов вы смотрите ?  если Nginx то .htaccess к нему ничего не имеет.  Возможно синтаксис неверен для вашей версии сервера попробуйте указать ip в строку через пробел.

Comment: @Digital Core Вот мой сервер https://cloud.mail.ru/public/HgZH/aTvgHwrga

Comment: Как вы проверили, что не работает запрет по ip ?

Comment: @Digital Core ввел свой ip в базу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант первый:**

```
## USER IP BANNING
<Limit GET POST>
order allow,deny
deny from 104.151.66.51
deny from 115.25.216.6
deny from 198.204.225.
deny from 210.22.
allow from all
</Limit>
```

**Вариант второй:**

```
order allow,deny
deny from 104.151.66.51 115.25.216.6 198.204.225.47
allow from all
```

Файл **.htaccess** должен лежать в корне сайта, и не переопределяться другим файлом.

**Вариант третий сервер Nginx:**

```nginx
location / {    
# block one workstation    
deny    192.168.1.1;    
# allow anyone in 192.168.1.0/24    
allow   192.168.1.0/24;    
# drop rest of the world    
deny    all;  }
```

Comment: К сожаление не работает

Comment: Приведите пример лога , как не работает , и скрин где лежат файлы.

Comment: я в гугл аналитике вижу вот с этого сайта заходят copyrightinstitute.org ip пробил на 2ip.ru

Comment: Я привёл три варианта , там на танке не проедешь, подозреваю, что движок сайта не ваш , то есть куплен, заказан, или фри.  На сайте могут быть копирайты, картинки, видео, товары, контент одним словом.
И этот контент может быть размещён в сети на других ресурсах, пользователь посетивший другой ресурс , на котором скажем расположена картинка с вашего сайта , его браузер скачает её с вашего сайта .

Comment: сайт чистый php+html

Comment: В третьем варианте я привёл конфигурацию для Nginx, танк не поедет !

Comment: в htaccess код вписывать c третьего варианта?

Comment: /usr/local/nginx/conf/

Comment: путь такой не вижу

Comment: Здесь у вас что записано AccessFileName

Comment: вот лог файл https://cloud.mail.ru/public/9MPT/Je7Ykuxfp

Comment: Поискал за вас , чтоб здесь не расписывать . http://www.apache.ru/docs/fishki.html

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// Получаем реальный IP
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// Список IP запрещенные
$ip_list = [
    '104.254.244.128',
    '173.245.58.177'
];

// Проверяем
if (in_array($ip, $ip_list)) {
    exit('Access from your IP is forbidden.');
}
```

?>

Comment: А если сайт не на php? :)

Comment: Вопрос был найден в категории PHP)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov на PHP

Comment: @АлексейКузнецов Алексей, этот код в шапку(head) или в тело (body)?

Comment: Пользователя банят по IP для того, чтоб не расходовать ресурсы сервера, а выполнение скриптов php как раз и есть расход ресурса.